# PHP NFe 4.0, como visualizar informações da nota fiscal?

Tags: php, nfe

Gostaria de visualizar a Nfe 4.0 em uma página PHP, andei estudando um pouco e achei diversos exemplos, mas até agora sem sucesso.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$xml= new DOMDocument;
$xml->load( "nfe.xml" );  
if (!$xml) {
echo "Erro ao abrir arquivo!";
exit;
} 
$ver = simplexml_import_dom($xml);

foreach ($ver as $valor) {

echo $valor->detItem->prod->xProd;

}

?>
```

**nfe.xml**

```
<det nItem="1"><prod><cProd>382597</cProd><cEAN>7899882306668</cEAN><xProd>VENT COL MOND NV06 6P 140W BR/AZ 110V</xProd><NCM>84145990</NCM><CEST>2108900</CEST><CFOP>5405</CFOP><uCom>PC</uCom><qCom>1.0000</qCom><vUnCom>189.0000000000</vUnCom><vProd>189.00</vProd>
```

`xProd` é descrição do produto, mas não aparece nada na página.

Qual seria o problema?

Comment: da um `var_dump($ver)` antes do foreach para confirmar

Comment: retornou  ["det"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (3) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["nItem"]=> string(1) "1" } ["prod"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (15) { ["cProd"]=> string(6) "382597" ["cEAN"]=> string(13) "7899882306668" ["xProd"]=> string(37) "VENT COL MOND NV06 6P 140W BR/AZ 110V" ["NCM"]=> string(8) "84145990" ["CEST"]=> string(7) "2108900" ["CFOP"]=> string(4) "5405" ["uCom"]=> string(2) "PC" ["qCom"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["vUnCom"]=> string(14) "189.0000000000" ["vProd"]=> string(6) "189.00"

Comment: tenta `echo $valor->det->prod->xProd;`,
você tem que seguir a nomenclatura idêntica , não precisa do foreach nesse caso, só para testar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php) (*diretamente já faz o papel das duas que você está utilizando*) e quando você quer `debugar` um código faça assim:

```
<?php    
    $xml= simplexml_load_file("nfe.xml");   
    if (!$xml) {
        echo "Erro ao abrir arquivo!";
        exit;
    } 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($xml);
```

que sua saída fica bem legal para entender como deve ser lido cada item, observe:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [nItem] => 1
        )

    [prod] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [cProd] => 382597
            [cEAN] => 7899882306668
            [xProd] => VENT COL MOND NV06 6P 140W BR/AZ 110V
            [NCM] => 84145990
            [CEST] => 2108900
            [CFOP] => 5405
            [uCom] => PC
            [qCom] => 1.0000
            [vUnCom] => 189.0000000000
            [vProd] => 189.00
        )    
)
```

sendo que essa instância tem um propriedade `nItem` que pode ser recuperada:

```
$attributes = $xml->attributes();   
$nItem = strval($attributes['nItem']);
```

e para recuperar a chave `prod` basicamente acessando cada item:

```
$children = $xml->children();

$data = array();
$data['cProd'] = (strval($children->prod->cProd));
$data['cEAN'] = (strval($children->prod->cEAN));
$data['xProd'] = (strval($children->prod->xProd));
$data['NCM'] = (strval($children->prod->NCM));
$data['CEST'] = (strval($children->prod->CEST));
$data['CFOP'] = (strval($children->prod->CFOP));
$data['uCom'] = (strval($children->prod->uCom));
$data['qCom'] = (strval($children->prod->qCom));
$data['vUnCom'] = (strval($children->prod->vUnCom));
$data['vProd'] = (strval($children->prod->vProd));
```

ou diretamente:

```
$data = ((array)$children->prod);
```

a partir disso só escrever echo `$data` e o `nome da chave` que você tem o `valor` de cada um:

```
echo $data['vProd']; //189.00
```

e assim por diante.

<sup>***Ref.***</sup>

- [A classe SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.construct.php)
- [A classe SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php)
- [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tenho mais uma duvida e quando tiver mais itens, por exemplo [nItem] => 1, [nItem] => 2, [nItem] => 3, nestes casos eu tenho que usar foreach ?

Comment: @Junior se for uma lista, um array sempre precisa iterar de alguma forma para recuperar os valores, então sim vai precisar. Tudo depende do formato o que está na sua pergunta é assim que lê se o formato for diferente, abra outro questionamento passando essas informações

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou seguir suas recomendações

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja uma pequena falta de atenção, o segredo é lembrar que se trata de um objeto multidimensional, que possui várias camadas contendo arrays ou outros obejtos:

```
  public 'det' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'nItem' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'prod' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'cProd' => string '382597' (length=6)
          public 'cEAN' => string '7899882306668' (length=13)
          public 'xProd' => string 'VENT COL MOND NV06 6P 140W BR/AZ 110V' (length=37)
          public 'NCM' => string '84145990' (length=8)
          public 'CEST' => string '2108900' (length=7)
          public 'CFOP' => string '5405' (length=4)
          public 'uCom' => string 'PC' (length=2)
          public 'qCom' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
          public 'vUnCom' => string '189.0000000000' (length=14)
          public 'vProd' => string '189.00' (length=6)
```

**(reproduzi o retorno que vc mandou em objeto direto no php, ao invés de xml, para a explicação, mas no seu retorno vai funcionar da mesma forma)**

Sendo assim, usando o `foreach()` assim como vc estava fazendo, acusaria um erro, pois não existe o objeto que vc estava tentando imprimir.

Como o `$ver` é composto por um `object 'det'`, que por sua vez é composto por um `array 'attributes'` e outro `object 'prod'`, o laço `foreach()` tenta imprimir de dentro do `array 'attributes'` como se fosse um objeto e acusa um erro.

Então ao invés de usar o `foreach()`, nesse caso, imprimir diretamente:

```
echo $ver->det->prod->xPrdo;
```

Ou definir uma nova variável para a raiz do `object 'prod'`:

```
$produto=$ver->det->prod;
```

Para facilitar o acesso às informações, podem ser opções para você:

```
echo $produto->xPred;
```

Edit:

No caso do arquivo `.xml`, usando a função [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php), assim como citado pelo @VirgilioNovic na primeira resposta, a representação não inclui o `det` assim como no exemplo que dei, então ficaria assim a impressão:

```
//leitura do arquivo
$xml=simplexml_load_file("nfe.xml");
//verifica se o arquivo abriu
if (!$xml) {
    echo "Erro ao abrir arquivo!";
    exit;
}
//imprime os componentes
echo $xml->prod->xProd;
```

Para facilitar o uso, aqui também pode ser usado uma variável para a raiz:

```
$produto=$xml->prod;
echo $produto->xPred;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação

Comment: @Junior, deu certo?

Comment: Estou verificando, pois essa parte que eu coloquei é uma parte da Nota Fiscal, e com o arquivo completo, não funcionou, mas com base na sua resposta, e na resposta do Virgilo eu estou estudando isso e vamos ver se eu consigo.